# RegEx difference for answer

Tags: regex

I've got a question that asks for a non-empty string that starts and ends with two 1's. The alphabet is {0,1}. It needs to match the string {11,111,1111,11000...11..0011} However many 1's and 0's in between doesn't matter as long as it ends with 2 1's. So far I've got this:

```
^(1{2,4}|(11[01]*0[01]*11))$
```

But my answer wasn't accepted because it needs to be simplified. Something along these lines `11(0|1)*(11)*` - this returns infinite 11's at the end so it's not accepted. I just can't figure it out can someone please push me in the right direction.

Comment: "that starts and ends with two 1's" I assume according to your examples you mean "starts or ends with two 1's" and could just use `(^11|11$)`

Comment: Check my answer below if that what you need

Comment: I'm thinking assertions. `(?<!1)(?:11[01]*11|11)(?!1)` or shorter `(?<!1)11[01]*(?<=11)(?!1)` or even  `^11[01]*(?<=11)$` if it's all one string. It's faster to have the assertion in the trailing position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest one:

```
11((0*1)*1)*
```

Explain:
When capturing 0 we must have one 1's at the end and another 1's at the outer group.

```
11   # match because 11 and Kleene star group is empty
111  # match 11(e1) -> 111
1111 # match 11(e1)1 --> 1111
11011  # match 11(01)1
11001  # non-match because 11(001) (no 1's at the end)
110111011    # match  11((01)1))(e1)((01)1)
```

Comment: Appreciate the comments. What you've written works, technically it will always start and end with two 1's which is what the question asks of me. It also returns and infinite amount of 1's. I don't see the problem with it but with the answer I had before, one of the reasons it wasn't accepted was the infinite 1's.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility `^(?=11)[01]*11$`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1c0grW/1). Here use look ahead to assert the string starts with `11` which fits the edge cases (`11`, `111`) pretty well here since it doesn't consume characters, and then match the whole string with `[01]*11$` which contains only 1 and 0 and ends with pattern `11`.

Or based on your existing approach `^(1{2,3}|11[01]*11)$` should work as well. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uELenW/1).

Answer (score 1):

`^(1{2,4}|11[01]+11)$`

`^(1{2,3}|11[01]*11)$`

`^(11|111|11[01]*11)$`

Answer (score 0):

Only 0 and 1? 
And starts and ends with 11? 
But also matching "11" or "111"?

Then this regex also does that:

```
^11(1|[01]*11)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last answer is very close. `(^11[01]*11$|^11+$)` would do.
I added the `OR 1+` to cover the 11 and 111 cases because the expression on the left covers anything that starts with 11 then either has some 0's and/or 1's or doesn't have them but then definitely has 11 again. This mean the shortest string it will match would be 1111. Hence the fix.

EDIT:
Sorry I answered too fast. Take Psidom's answer it's perfect.